# How to use variable column name in filter in Django ORM?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, orm

I have two tables BloodBank(id, name, phone, address) and BloodStock(id, a_pos, b_pos, a_neg, b_neg, bloodbank_id). I want to fetch all the columns from two tables where the variable column name (say bloodgroup) which have values like a_pos or a_neg... like that and their value should be greater than 0. How can I write ORM for the same?

SQL query is written like this to get the required results.

```
sql="select * from public.bloodbank_bloodbank as bb, public.bloodbank_bloodstock as bs where bs."+blood+">0 and bb.id=bs.bloodbank_id order by bs."+blood+" desc;"
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
bloodbanks = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Show your models... Also don't write queries this way (concatenating strings to make a query), it makes you vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be more specific in your questions, but I believe you have a variable called `blood` which contains the string name of the column and that the columns a_pos, b_pos, etc. are numeric.

You can use a dictionary to create keyword arguments from strings:

```
filter_dict = {bloodstock__blood + '__gt': 0}
bloodbanks = Bloodbank.objects.filter(**filter_dict)
```

This will get you Bloodbank objects that have a related bloodstock with a greater than zero value in the bloodgroup represented by the blood variable.

Note that the way I have written this, you don't get the bloodstock columns selected, and you may get duplicate bloodbanks. If you want to get eliminate duplicate bloodbanks you can add `.distinct()` to your query. The bloodstocks are available for each bloodbank instance using `.bloodstock_set.all()`.

The ORM will generate SQL using a join. Alternatively, you can do an EXISTS in the where clause and no join.

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

filter_dict = {blood + '__gt': 0}
exists = Exists(Bloodstock.objects.filter(
    bloodbank_id=OuterRef('id'),
    **filter_dict
)
bloodbanks = Bloodbank.objects.filter(exists)
```

There will be no need for a `.distinct()` in this case.